# Can I make VirtualBox Mac OS X installation from my installation disk?

Tags: virtualbox

I have the original install disk that came with my macbook.

I would like to make a VirtualBox Mac desktop install, can I use this disk? Can I make an ISO copy of the disk so I don't need it physically?

1. Is it possible?
2. Is it legal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not officially supported -- the only truly legitimate way would be to buy the server edition of OSX, which is.

( http://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Guest_OSes for further details. )

So, short answer, your disk won't work. If you do want such a virtual machine, go for the server edition.

Alternatively, a modified iso available from your favourite bittorrent tracker should work -- there are editions which have been modified to work on standard x86 hardware, which will function in virtualbox. That'll break Apple's EULA quite handily.